# Powershell Script for deleting AD User & Profile

Tags: powershell, active-directory

im a complete newbie at coding/powershell. I "wrote" this small Script

```
$Username = Read-Host -Prompt 'Bitte den Usernamen eingeben'

$HomeDirectory = '\\server\user'
$ProfilePath = '\\server\profiles'
$TsProfiles = '\\server\tsprofiles'

foreach ($user in $Username) {
    Remove-ADUser -Identity $user
}

foreach ($user in $Username) {
    Remove-Item "$HomeDirectory\$user" -Recurse -Force -Verbose -whatif
}

foreach ($user in $Username) {
    Remove-Item -Path "$ProfilePath\$user" -Recurse -Force -Verbose -whatif
}

foreach ($user in $Username) {
    Remove-Item "$TsProfiles\$user*" -Recurse -Force -Verbose -whatif
}
```

Now this Script is running fine. But i have one small "problem"

1.) For some User there is no TsProfiles or ProfilePath or User. So when i run the script i get this error

```
At line:15 char:5
+     Remove-Item -Path "$ProfilePath\$user" -Recurse -Force -Verbose - ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\server\profiles\myusername:String) [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

For sure because there is no such path as the user dont have a Profile in that folder. Now im searching for a solution which can write me something like this to a Logfile

** HomeDirectory of %Username% deleted **

** TsProfiles of %Username% deleted **

** Profilepath for %Username% not found **

Comment: I think you want something like `If(Test-Path "$HomeDirectory\$user"){Remove-Item "$HomeDirectory\$user" -Recurse -Verbose -Force -WhatIf; Add-Content -Value "** HomeDirectory of $User deleted **" -Path $LogFile}Else{Add-Content -Value "** HomeDirectory of $User not found **" -Path $LogFile}`

Comment: Thank you so much ! Thats working perfect ! Would it be possible to log if the user was deleted also ? I dont know how to check it there as i cant use test-path :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first off you should have it all in one loop, not several loops, but you are only working with 1 user, so there's nothing to loop through. We'll just remove all the loops.

Then, if you want to output if you deleted something you need to check if that something is there. For users we can use `Get-ADUser`, and for file paths we can use `Test-Path`.

```
$Username = Read-Host -Prompt 'Bitte den Usernamen eingeben'

$HomeDirectory = '\\server\user'
$ProfilePath = '\\server\profiles'
$TsProfiles = '\\server\tsprofiles'

If(Get-ADUser $username){
    Remove-ADUser -Identity $username
    Add-Content -Value "** User Account for $Username deleted **" -Path $LogFile
}Else{
    Add-Content -Value "** User Account for $Username not found **" -Path $LogFile
}
If(Test-Path "$HomeDirectory\$username"){
    Remove-Item "$HomeDirectory\$username" -Recurse -Verbose -Force -WhatIf
    Add-Content -Value "** HomeDirectory of $Username deleted **" -Path $LogFile
}Else{
    Add-Content -Value "** HomeDirectory of $Username not found **" -Path $LogFile
}
If(Test-Path "$ProfilePath\$username"){
    Remove-Item "$ProfilePath\$username" -Recurse -Verbose -Force -WhatIf
    Add-Content -Value "** ProfilePath of $Username deleted **" -Path $LogFile
}Else{
    Add-Content -Value "** ProfilePath of $Username not found **" -Path $LogFile
}
If(Test-Path "$TsProfiles\$username"){
    Remove-Item "$TsProfiles\$username" -Recurse -Verbose -Force -WhatIf
    Add-Content -Value "** TsProfiles of $Username deleted **" -Path $LogFile
}Else{
    Add-Content -Value "** TsProfiles of $Username not found **" -Path $LogFile
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's my bad, I forgot we removed the loop so we need to use `$Username` instead of just `$User`. I updated the answer, it should work as intended now.

Comment: Sadly the part with the user isnt working. If i use a username which dont exist i get the error from Powershell

Get-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: 'asdsada' under: 'DC=int,DC=domain,DC=de'.

But there is no log entry that the user wasnt found i just see that the folders arent found.

Comment: ah, right, `Get-ADUser` doesn't like looking for a specific user and not finding it. As an alternative you can do `Get-ADUser -filter "samAccountName -eq '$Username'"` instead, and that won't error on you and should work as expected

Comment: I put that code in and its working just had to change $username to $user :P Now the final question is could i also show the error when the user dont exists in the Powershell window ? Right now you enter a wrong name and have to check the logfile if there was an error.

Comment: Got it :) Just added 

Write-Output "** AD-User $User was not found **"

At every line with the correct text :)

Comment: I like `Write-Warning` for things like that personally, but that's me. If this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: I will try that one also ! Im so happy its working and i now use write-host so i could change the color of the output so the guys using that script can see green and red haha. Thank you so much i learned a lot from this script :) Happy there are ppl like you around here helping so hard !